# Superfish menu with user id as a parameter

Tags: routes, navigation

My question is how to get the user id on a URL path when creating a link in a superfish menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this module [Menu token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token)

> Menu Token module provides tokens, that could be used in title or in
>   path of menu items (links). For example, if you create a menu item
>   with path: "user/[current-user:uid]", the url will be changed "on fly"
>   to: "user/1" (assuming you are user 1).